# How to kill dead cursors in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, timeout, pymongo, database-cursor

When querying a MongoDB collection, if the read will take a while, the cursor times out.
There's a `timeout=False` option, which makes the cursor not time out, and then it must be closed manually.

When a script crashes with an open cursor, that cursor presumably just stays alive in the DB until the next restart.
In the MMS monitoring dashboard, these are visible as a high constant in the "cursors" chart.

[image: mms cursors]

What are the consequences of this?
And how can I kill these cursors manually?

Comment: Use the [`close` method](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.close) of the cursor object. The cost of having open cursors is the memory required on the server for the cursor. It is minimal but can become a problem if the number of open cursors grows into the hundreds or thousands. The cursor will also be auto-closed if the cursor object is garbage collected by Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if my script has died, and python did not gc the cursors and close them? I was wondering if there's a way to find them and close them.

Comment: Not as far as I know. It would be possible with the feature requested in [SERVER-3090](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3090) but that hasn't been implemented yet. Clearly, you should avoid immortal cursors. You can set the timeout to be large but finite, or you can use a sort on the cursor and reopen the cursor from the last seen element if it closes after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by wdberkeley, this doesn't currently exist, but is a new feature requested in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3090.